# How to bypass Browser add-ons from Blocking Azure Application Insight Logs

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm using Application Insights [JS SDK React Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js) to log application insights data to Azure. This data publishing could get blocked by some browser extensions such as Ad Blocker, Privacy Badger, etc. In my case analytics got blocked by Privacy Badger while experimenting.

[image]

I know it can be prevented by disabling relevant add-ons for the particular site from the browser. Just wondering is there a particular way to prevent this from implementation side without asking users to disable their add-ons.

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the entire purpose of using "Ad Block" type extensions if websites could simply bypass them? This is similar to asking if there is a way to bypass CAPTCHA so a bot can scrape a site.

Comment: @Andy Yeah I agree with you. But app insights are something developers need to make applications with a higher UX. IMO insights shouldn't get blocked by browser extensions unless the extension is particularly blocking insight data. In this case we should at least have a way to reconfigure Azure insights sdk to send data to one of our endpoints so that I can apply a proxy approach. Any literature I found so far didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered building a proxy to forward traffic to your own domain before then passing it off to App Insights?

https://github.com/shaneochotny/ApplicationInsights-JS-Proxy

> Show how to proxy requests from the Application Insights Javascript SDK instead of sending telemetry directly to dc.services.visualstudio.com. This allows you to do things such as use your own custom domain and/or hide the Instrumentation Key.

There are step by step instructions in that link to configure this

Comment: Yeah I'm actually looking for a proxy approach. But that documentation isn't clear on the sixth step. i.e. "add endpointUrl to the configuration". Can you show how to change the endpoint url in JS sdk?

Comment: Based on the quote from point 6
"Remove instrumentationKey and add endpointUrl to the configuration."

I would assume this: 

`const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({ config: {
  endpointUrl: "https://analytics.shaneochotny.com"
} });`

As per [Msft docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS) though I've not tried this